# After publishing my API PUT method showing 400 Bad Request?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, postman

In local system my PUT method is working properly, but when I am hosting that API in server, it is throwing 400 Bad Request from Postman. Please suggest any one.

Comment: I guess you are using PUT in postman?

Comment: You need to add more details in your question for others to help. Please provide some code lines which is giving error.

Comment: Yes, i am using PUT method and Basic Authentication for updating the record.
and normal ado.net query to update the record
Locally its working fine. But when i am publishing in server. Its throwing 400 Bad Request Error

Answer (score 1):

I'll be more than happy to help you out if you can provide more details about the questions — screenshots or code snippets.

Nevertheless, the most common cause of a 400 Bad Request Error is simply inputting an incorrect URL. Would you please check the endpoint, params, and other things associated with the URL?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, this is not an answer and should be added as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Okay Lets check some basic standards to be followed.
Check the API call statement syntax are correct. And also check the API link and the (/) in the code. It plays major role in the API calls.
And if you give more details I can help Particularly in the area.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, this is not an answer and should be added as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your valuable feedback.
Finally I got the solution to this problem. Actually this error is due to the bad data format. I used some date field in the input. Due to that date format it was throwing the error in server. The format is not supported in server.